# There is a widget to copy and get images from clipboard?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web, clipboard

Goal: Copy an image from HDD and get it(by pasting it) on my Flutter web app

What I tried:

- Clipboard doesn't support image type.
- Pasteboard works if I add images manually (from the app), but I need to add images from the desktop by copying it and for this it doesn't work. In particular the error is that image type is not supported.
- Manually doing it using Javascript APIs and the result is the same of pasteboard.

I hope that my answer is clear. Thank you!

Example code using Pasteboard:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pasteboard/pasteboard.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {

            // works if you copy text
            var text = await Pasteboard.text;
            print("text: $text");

            // works if you copy text, returns null if you copy an image
            var html = await Pasteboard.html;
            print("text: $html");
            
            // Returns always null
            var image = await Pasteboard.image;
            print(image);
          },
          child: const Text('Click me', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok... But, where is your code?

Comment: I'm not searching for a fix to my code... I'm searching if someone did it and knows a tool that works.

Comment: @pierpy I have added an example code using Pasteboard. When you click on the button, clipboard content is printed